# Hypothesis of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Why do we need compactness in the space as hypothesis in Stone-Weierstrass Theorem?

> **Theorem:**
>   Let $A \subset C(K)$ such that
>
> 1. $A$ is a subalgebra that vanishes nowhere.
> 2. For each $x, y \in K $ with $x \neq  y $, there exists $f \in A$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.
>
> Then $ \overline A = C(K)$, where $C(K)$ is the space of continuous functions over the compact space $K$.

Comment: Note: C(K) means the space of continuous functions in a compact metric space K

Comment: You can actually do Stone-Weierstrass in much more generality. You don't need to only work on compact spaces.

Comment: You have to specify what topology to use on $C(K)$ if $K$ is not compact.  The uniform norm no longer makes sense.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes I know but I'm taking a first course of analysis so we are in a particular case (I guess) of the general theorem

Comment: @NateEldredge K is compact in the theorem I'm considering

Comment: Right. My point is.. it's a bit hard to say exactly because it sounds like you're asking for "only if" for compactness in the context of Stone-Weierstrass. Compactness just lets you use uniform continuity ideas, IIRC, to facilitate the proof. Without compactness, you can't guarantee uniform continuity which makes the proof less obvious (and in fact you need to add some restrictions to make it work for noncompact spaces).

Comment: @CameronWilliams so basically we need compactness to use uniform continuity therefore we can assure  continuity in all functions of the space?

Comment: It's been four or five years since I last read through the proof in detail. I'm not entirely sure on the specific details. Maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: Lang's proof in "Real and Functional Analysis" (my favorite) states the theorem exactly as you have it. He first proves a lemma under an additional assumption on the functions in your subalgebra, wherein he uses a finite open cover (hence, compactness of $K$) to construct a new function in $K$ within epsilon of any given continuous function. His construction is a bit too technical to lend itself well to a one-sentence recap, but it's not too horrible to read through. He then uses the lemma to prove the theorem pretty quickly.

Comment: Have you tried reading a proof of the theorem?  If you have some particular proof in mind then if you share it we can point out explicitly where compactness is used.  It's unclear what you find unsatisfying about Nate Eldredge's comment, which shows that the statement of the theorem may not even make sense if $K$ is not compact (though there are ways to try to make it make sense).

Comment: @EricWofsey yes I have one. Do you want me to post the photos of the proof (the proof is in Real Analysis by Pugh)? or do you wanna look for it in pugh's book?

Comment: @EricWofsey I've tried since days agooo..if you don't believe me, check my questions that I've published before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stone-Weierstrass theorem can be generalized in various ways, as discussed below (mostly based on *General Topology* by Willard, section 44). But presenting things in the greatest possible generality usually goes counter to the purpose of writing a textbook. Textbook authors are more concerned with presenting an insightful, digestible proof, and with proving the results that are actually used later.

#### Functions vanishing at infinity

The easiest generalization is to consider the algebra $C_0(X)$ of functions "vanishing at infinity" on a locally compact space $X$. This is the form that  [Wikipedia presents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version). It's not really much of a generalization, since one can consider the one-point compactification of $X$, denoted $\widehat {X}=X\cup\{\infty\}$, and extend functions to $\infty$ by zero. By including the constant function in subalgebra $A$ one gets to the point where the compact case of Stone-Weierstrass can be used. Then one observes that to approximate a function that vanishes at $\infty$,  one does not need the constant functions after all.

#### Bounded functions

The space of all *bounded* real-valued continuous functions $C_b(X)$ still has the uniform norm, so one can hope to generalize the Stone-Weierstrass theorem verbatim. This does not actually work, though: let $X=[0,\infty)$ and denote by $A$ the algebra of all continuous functions $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists. This is a closed subalgebra which vanishes nowhere and separates points, but it does not coincide with $C_b(X)$; for example $\sin x\notin A$.

To state a version of Stone-Weierstrass theorem for this case, let's say that $Z\subset X$ is a *zero set* if there exists a continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $Z=f^{-1}(0)$. An algebra $A$ *separates zero sets* if for any two disjoint zero sets $Z_1$ and $Z_1$ there is $f\in A$ such that $\overline{f(Z_1)}\cap \overline{f(Z_2)}$ is empty.

**Theorem**. Suppose $X$ is a Tychonoff space (also known as $T_{3\frac12}$ space). If an algebra $A\subset C_b(X)$ separates zero sets, contains constant functions, and is closed in the uniform norm, then $A=C_b(X)$.

The proof still involves compactification of $X$, but this time one needs the [Stone–Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification).

#### Compact-open topology

If one considers $C(X)$, the set of all continuous functions on a non-compact space $X$, then that's no longer a normed space. While uniform convergence still makes sense, one can't hope to have uniform approximation here: for example, $f(x)=e^x$ cannot be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $\mathbb{R}$. A natural decision is to equip $C(X)$ with the compact-open topology; i.e., it's a locally convex space with topology generated by seminorms $\|f\|_K = \sup_K|f|$, for all compact subsets $K\subset X$.

**Theorem**. Suppose $X$ is a Tychonoff space. If $A\subset C(X)$ is an algebra that is closed in the compact-open topology, separates the points of $X$, and contains the constant functions, then $A=C(X)$.

For example, this implies that for every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that 
$$
\forall M\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|x|\le M}|f(x)-p_n(x)| =0
$$

#### Topology of uniform convergence

Willard presents two more forms of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, using the topology of uniform convergence on $C(X)$ (which makes it a very disconnected topological space). They impose strong additional assumptions on the algebras of functions and are too involved to be stated here.

Comment: This is very nice and insightful!

Answer (score -3):

We need  the compactness of M because we are gonna cover it with a finite subcover of neightboors of a given point q arbitrary.

What a simple reasoning..

Comment: WHO gave me -1? and why??