# Generalization of Stone-Weierstrass for Tychonoff Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request

A well-known generalization of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem is the following:

**Theorem:** Suppose $X$ is a Tychonoff space. If $A\subset C(X,\mathbb{R})=\{f:X\to\mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ is continuous}\}$ is a subalgebra which separates points and contains the constant functions, then $A$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the compact-open topology.

This result can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265822/hypothesis-of-stone-weierstrass-theorem) (a previous question on this website), and also in the introduction to the Wikipedia article about the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

My questions are as follows:

1. Can someone direct me to a proof of this generalization?
2. Can the hypothesis that *$A$ contains the constant functions* be replaced by the hypothesis that *$A$ vanishes at no point of $X$*?

The author of the answer to the previous question I referenced on this website mentions that the proofs he or she cites are mostly based on Section 44 of Willard's *General Topology*. I looked at that section and found that the above theorem and other generalizations of Stone-Weierstrass are given as exercises so their proofs are not included.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kelley (General Topology, p. 244/245 in exercise R of the chapter on function spaces) formulates it as follows:

> If $X$ is a topological space and the family $C(X)$ of all continuous real-valued functions on $X$ is given the topology of uniform convergence on compacta (which is the compact-open topology according to Thm. 11 in the same chapter), then each subalgebra of $C(X)$ that has the *two-point property* is dense in $C(X)$.

(the two-point property being that for each $x \neq y$ in $X$ and any two reals $a,b$  there is an $f \in C(X)$ with $f(x) =a \land f(y)=b$; it's implied by all constant functions being in the subalgebra plus the subalgebra separating points, according to the exercise's preamble, and that is indeed easy to see, and baby Rudin shows that nowhere vanishing plus separating points together also imply it; this shows that you don't always need all constant functions to be in the subalgebra). Having constants + nowhere vanishing together might not imply it, though, not sure..

He refers to

M.H. Stone *The generalized Weierstrass approximation theorem*, Math. Mag. **21** (1948) 167-184, 254-273

for further discussion (so I presume there's a proof or reference to it there).

I couldn't find a similarly broad theorem in Engelking (usually my go-to book), though he refers to the same paper, as Willard does too BTW (!)

The encyclopedia of general topology's [chapter on function spaces](https://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/publications/the_papers/ency/c20-function-spaces.pdf) mentions (p151 section7, almost as an aside) that the theorem holds for general spaces and subalgebras with constant functions and separating points (so implying the two-point property again) in the compact-open topology, but gives no explicit reference for it. The three general references it does give might help, though.

Maybe the proof reduces to the compact case (for which Engelking has a full proof, and Kelly extensive hints) in some way? I'd look for the MH Stone paper and see what it has. It might be the original reference for all of this. (it isn't called the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for nothing: Weierstrass did the special case of polynomaials on a compact real interval, nothing as general as Stone's contribution).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I looked at the MH Stone paper and he seems to assume that $A$ contains constant functions as well.  I believe the assumption that $A$ includes constant functions is implicitly just the assumption that $A$ is unital. Even in Baby Rudin, for example, Rudin does not assume in the section on Stone Weierstrass that $A$ is unital, and his workaround is to assume that it does not vanish at any point. Maybe the version I gave in my question is similarly just the version of that theorem where $A$ is not necessarily unital.

Comment: @JWP_HTX Yes, if it contains 1 (the constant one function) from being unital, it will contain all of them, clearly. I'm not sure that subalgebra always implies having the 1 in it, though. And an algebra can separate points and still vanish at some element, which kills denseness. If $A$ separates points and has constants, it obeys the 2-point property, and that is the principle used in its proof, I think. But without any constants and just never vanishing at a point, maybe $A$ need not obey the 2-point property? I cannot think of a natural example here.

Comment: @JWP_HTX Is the Stone paper freely available? I'd like to see it.

Comment: @JWP_HTX Rudin proves that nowhere vanishing plus point separating implies 2-pp. So in your case you can demand that $A$ has these two properties instead, and then you don't need constant functions.

Comment: I found the Stone paper via JSTOR through my university, so I don't think it's free unless you have access to a similar database. And thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JWP_HTX You're welcome!